# Ignore null values in JSON dictionary - Python 3

Tags: json, api, python-3.7

I am starting to learn python and unable to figure this out (spent hours googling it).

Here's what I have:

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

table_data = []
for i in data['items']:
    attendeeid = i['attendee id']
    if 'reg: how hear ' in i:
        howhear = i['reg: how hear ']
    else:
        howhear = 'No Data'
    orderid = i['order_id']
    totalprice = i['total price']
    ordernumber = i['order_number']
    email = i['email']
    state = i['state']
    country = i['country']
    companyname = i['company name']
    packagename = i['package name']
    orderdate = i['order date']
    pipedurl = i['piped url']
    revenue = i['revenue']
    lineitemquantity = i['line item quantity']
    timebaseitemprice = i['time base item price']
    table_data.append([attendeeid, howhear, orderid, totalprice, ordernumber, email, state, country, companyname, packagename, orderdate, pipedurl, revenue, lineitemquantity, timebaseitemprice])
```

However, I am finding that not all records have a value in the state field. How do I create an exception to address null state values?

thanks.

Comment: use `dict.get()`

Comment: thank you, but do you mind elaborating? I am still learning...